# How to create a flutter widget from the list of json response dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi have json response from the api , I want to loop through it and create a Nested widget something like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_simple_treeview. The response contain a children node it can have just 1 children node or children can have and children node and so on it's a dynamic.
Does any one have a good solution for this? Thank you in advance.

```
{
  "data": {
    "categories": {
      "total_count": 1,
      "items": [
        {
          "uid": "Mg==",
          "name": "Default Category",
          "children": [
            {
              "children_count": "3",
              "uid": "Mw==",
              "name": " T-shirt",
              "description": null,
              "level": 2,
              "children": [
                {
                  "uid": "MTM=",
                  "children_count": "2",
                  "name": "Mens Collection",
                  "description": null,
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "children_count": "4",
                      "name": "Summer Ware",
                      "description": null,
                      "level": 4,
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "children_count": "0",
                          "name": "Round Neck",
                          "description": null,
                          "level": 5
                        },
                        {
                          "children_count": "0",
                          "name": "Free Size",
                          "description": null,
                          "level": 5
                        },
                        {
                          "children_count": "0",
                          "name": "V Neck",
                          "description": null,
                          "level": 5
                        },
                        {
                          "children_count": "0",
                          "name": "Slim Fit",
                          "description": null,
                          "level": 5
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "children_count": "0",
                      "name": "Office Ware",
                      "description": null,
                      "level": 4,
                      "children": []
                    }
                  ],
                  "level": 3
                },
                {
                  "uid": "MTQ=",
                  "children_count": "0",
                  "name": "Womens Collection",
                  "description": null,
                  "children": [],
                  "level": 3
                },
                {
                  "uid": "MTU=",
                  "children_count": "0",
                  "name": "Kids Collection",
                  "description": null,
                  "children": [],
                  "level": 3
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "children_count": "0",
              "uid": "NA==",
              "name": "Electronic",
              "description": null,
              "level": 2,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "children_count": "2",
              "uid": "NQ==",
              "name": "Accessories",
              "description": null,
              "level": 2,
              "children": [
                {
                  "uid": "Ng==",
                  "children_count": "0",
                  "name": "Caps",
                  "description": null,
                  "children": [],
                  "level": 3
                },
                {
                  "uid": "MTA=",
                  "children_count": "2",
                  "name": "Bags",
                  "description": null,
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "children_count": "0",
                      "name": "School Bag",
                      "description": null,
                      "level": 4,
                      "children": []
                    },
                    {
                      "children_count": "0",
                      "name": "Travel Bag",
                      "description": null,
                      "level": 4,
                      "children": []
                    }
                  ],
                  "level": 3
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "children_count": "0",
              "uid": "OQ==",
              "name": "Kids",
              "description": null,
              "level": 2,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Currently i have implemented as below image , but its a manually creating a widget, which means if there is a new  children added to Slim Fit it cant create that widget
[image]